# Can I decompress a .gzip file with tar?

Tags: macos, tar, gzip

I downloaded a `.gz` file with anonymized Census data and around 1 GB compressed. I am unable to inspect it with `tar`:

```
$ tar -tf census.csv.gz 
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

but I can inspect and decompress it with `gzip`:

```
$ gzip -l census.csv.gz 
  compressed uncompressed  ratio uncompressed_name
   949332135    886077017  -7.2% census.csv
$ gzip -d census.csv.gz
```

I can also extract the archive by double-clicking, which opens Archive Utility. I am more confused because the `man` page for `tar` says that it has the gzip method.

Can `tar` list and decompress `.gz` files?

Notes: `gzip` is `/usr/bin/gzip` on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5.

Comment: I think your confusion is that "tar" is an (uncompressed) format to put multiple files into a single file. Tar can optionally comress this tar file as part of it's job (making a tar.gz file or .the file) - the key being that gzip compresses a stream/single file while tar converts multiple files into 1 - this you would not typically use tar on a single file.

Comment: @davidgo I think I see. Is `tar` able to decompress `tar.gz` files but not `.gz` files (without `.tar`)?

Comment: That would seem right to me. (I'm not at my PC - so I can't be sure there is not done obscure switch to allow it - but I can say tar is not typically used for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks @davidgo. Would you like to post an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TAR is typically used to merge / demux multiple files to/from single archive  (TAR comes from Tape Archive - i.e. working with a data stream to be written to or read from tape), and it can optionally work with a compressed archive (using gzip among other options), but it was not designed as a general purpose compression / decompression tool.

Similarly, GZIP generally only works on a single file (where it compresses more then 1 file, it does each one individually).

A `tar.gz` (or `.tgz`) indicates a group of files which have been combined into a single stream with TAR, and then `gzip`ped. TAR can handle these files, but not general purpose single `.gz` files.

Read more [at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#Suffixes_for_compressed_files).